# sqlalchemy query works only when selecting specific rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm very confused. I'm trying to run a simple query on a database:

```
def get_not_tested_calculations(self, location_id: int):
        with self.session.begin() as sess:
            sel = select(MHICalculation).filter(
                MHICalculation.applicable_location == location_id,
                MHICalculation.is_tested == False
            )
            res = [i[0] for i in sess.execute(sel).all()]
            return res
```

What I keep getting is a whole load of `<db.schema.MHICalculation object at 0x000002795B13B4F0>` objects.

When I inspect the select object the query itself looks correct:

```
SELECT mhi_calculation.id, mhi_calculation.mhi_type, mhi_calculation.added_date, mhi_calculation.added_by, mhi_calculation.mhi_cutoff, mhi_calculation.truck_window_size, mhi_calculation.ochreous_goethite_min, mhi_calculation.ochreous_goethite_max, mhi_calculation.kaolinite_min, mhi_calculation.kaolinite_max, mhi_calculation.hematite_ultrafines_min, mhi_calculation.hematite_ultrafines_max, mhi_calculation.hematite_lump_min, mhi_calculation.hematite_lump_max, mhi_calculation.hematite_moisture_min, mhi_calculation.hematite_moisture_max, mhi_calculation.goethite_ultrafines_min, mhi_calculation.goethite_ultrafines_max, mhi_calculation.goethite_lump_min, mhi_calculation.goethite_lump_max, mhi_calculation.goethite_moisture_min, mhi_calculation.goethite_moisture_max, mhi_calculation.truck_count, mhi_calculation.is_tested, mhi_calculation.applicable_location
FROM mhi_calculation
WHERE mhi_calculation.applicable_location = :applicable_location_1 AND mhi_calculation.is_tested = false
```

It works fine when I specify a column, for example:

```
def get_not_tested_calculations(self, location_id: int):
        with self.session.begin() as sess:
            sel = select(MHICalculation.id).filter(
                MHICalculation.applicable_location == location_id,
                MHICalculation.is_tested == False
            )        
            res = [i[0] for i in sess.execute(sel).all()]
            return res
```

And the query is pretty much the same, albeit shorter, of course:

```
SELECT mhi_calculation.id 
FROM mhi_calculation
WHERE mhi_calculation.applicable_location = :applicable_location_1 AND mhi_calculation.is_tested = false
```

I've been trying all the different ways but for some strange reason can't get it to work at all. I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4.27 with Python 3.9.7.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: The query is returning instances of the model.  What are you expecting?

Comment: @snakecharmerb the text version of the query appears to be correct and should be returning values for the columns of the model. In this case how do I query all the columns of the model without specifying them manually?

Comment: If you want raw values rather than the model instance it's probably easiest to query the model's underlying `__table__`: `select(MHICalculation.__table__).where(...)`.  You may need to use core syntax (`where` rather than `filter`) but you can still execute with `session.execute`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, if I query it using `__table__` and a `where` clause then I just get the **id** column of MHICalculation table, which is the primary key. But I don't get any of the other columns. Essentially, the result is the same as in my second example where I directly queried `MHICalculation.id`

Comment: Probably `[i[0] for i in sess.execute(sel).all()]` is extracting only the `id`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, oh yeah! Thanks! My bad.